# SwiftUI: vertical align dynamic sized Rectangle with Spacer in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

It seems there is a potential bug in SwiftUI. I am trying to put a rectangle with opacity 0.5 on top of an image.

[image]

When I try to fix the transparent rectangle on top, from 100px width, it goes down instead of sticking to the top.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
      ZStack {
            VStack {
                Image("movistar")
                    .resizable(capInsets: EdgeInsets(), resizingMode: .stretch)
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .cornerRadius(8)
                    .padding(15)
                    .frame(minWidth: Global.SCREEN_WIDTH)
            }
            
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, opacity: 0.5))
                        .frame(width: 110, height: Global.SCREEN_WIDTH / 4)
                        
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .scaledToFit()
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .padding(15)
            .frame(width: Global.SCREEN_WIDTH, height: Global.SCREEN_WIDTH)
```

Comment: I would like to insert: Global.SCREEN_WIDTH as the Rectangle frame width

Comment: I also think that the HStack are not necessary, but just wanted to test any potential solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no bug here. If you add a .background to all of your layers, you will see that because of the way you set up the view (ie. Spacer, scaledToFit, etc.) the actual frames of the views are not necessarily the edges of the image. You also have not set the alignment of any of the Stacks or Frames.

There are many ways to do what you are trying to do, but I believe this is the simplest:

```
var body: some View {
    Image("movistar")
        .resizable(capInsets: EdgeInsets(), resizingMode: .stretch)
        .scaledToFit()
        .cornerRadius(8)
        .frame(minWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
        .overlay(
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, opacity: 0.5))
                .frame(width: 110, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 4)
            , alignment: .top
        )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got into a solution: .scaleToFit() was messing with the VStack(). After deleting, it worked perfectly. I also got rid of the HStack().